# Firebase filtering results

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question I read from realtime database 1000 last records but I need for example record number 100,200,300... can I do this ? I'm going to make chart and I want for example only show there every 10th measurement. My databse looks like that:
[image]

```
 firebase.database().ref("Humidity").ref.orderByChild("time").limitToLast(1000).on("child_added",snapshot => {
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to built offset-based pagination, where you first show the most recent 100 messages, then the next 100, etc. That is not how pagination in Firebase works.

Pagination on Firebase follows a cursor model, and is based on knowing an anchor node. For example, if you've first shown the 100 most recent messages, you know the timestamp and key of the oldest message you've shown. You can then get the 100 messages before that with:

```
firebase.database().ref("Humidity")
  .orderByChild("time")
  .endAt(oldestTimeValue, oldestKey) //  new
  .limitToLast(100)
  .on("child_added",snapshot => {
```

This:

- orders the nodes by their `time` value.
- finds the node whose `time` is `oldestTimeValue` and whose key (typically a push key like `-M...`) is `oldestKey` (just in case there are multiple nodes with the same `time` value).
- then takes the 100 nodes *before* that one.

Comment: That's probably not what I wanted, I'm going to make chart with humidity measurements and the humidity is measured every second but on the chart I want to show measurements after every 100 second so I have limitToLast(1000) and then I have 1000 measurments on my chart but I want only 10 measurments:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000

Comment: Ah, that's different indeed, but unfortunately not necessarily in a good way. Firebase can't get every 100th key automatically. If you know the keys of the nodes you want to retrieve, you can retrieve them individually from `ref("Humidity").child("100")`. This results in multiple calls, but that's not nearly as slow as you may expect, because Firebase pipelines the requests over a single connection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786.

Comment: If you don't know the specific keys, or another unique value, of the nodes to retireve though, there's not much more you can do than reading all the relevant nodes and skipping the irrelevant ones in your application code.